# How to move value of DL and DH to AX and BX register in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

How to move value of DL and DH to AX and BX register in NASM assembly?
I tried with:

```
mov ax, dl
mov bx, dh
```

But it not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: It wont compile , it eject error while compiling

Comment: ... and what is that error?

Comment: "invalid combination of opcode and operands"

Comment: So it's telling you the exact problem; you can't use those registers together in a `mov` instruction. Hold on, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those register combinations are forbidden.  Use:

```
mov al, dl
mov bl, dh
```

You might find it useful to read the [documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Comment: Assuming this is a current processor, use: | movzx ax,dl | movzx bx,dh | . If movzx is not supported, clear ax and bx first: | xor ax,ax | xor bx,bx | mov al,dl | mov bl,dh | .

Comment: Thanks @rcgldr. I thought those moves would clear the top 8 bits on their own. Or is that just for moves in to `ax` vs `eax` and the like?

Comment: Nothing is cleared automatically, use movzx to zero out the upper part of the destination, and movsx to sign extend into the upper part of the destination.